# Replay Kafka topic with Server-Sent-Events

Tags: spring, multithreading, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, server-sent-events

I'm thinking about the following use-case and would like to validate if this approach is conceptually valid.

The goal is to expose a long-running *Server-Sent-Event* (SSE) endpoint in Spring replaying the same Kafka topic for each incoming connection (with some user-specific filtering).

The SSE is exposed in this way:

```
  @GetMapping("/sse")
  public SseEmitter sse() {
    SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter();

    Executors
          .newSingleThreadExecutor()
          .execute(() -> dummyDataProducer.generate()  // kafka ultimately
                .forEach(payload -> {
                  try {
                    sseEmitter.send(payload);
                  } catch (IOException ex) {
                    sseEmitter.completeWithError(ex);
                  }
                }));

    return sseEmitter;
  }
```

From the other side, there is a `KafkaListener` method (`ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` is used) :

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "${app.kafka.topic1}")
  public void receive(
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) Integer id,
        @Payload Object payload) {
    // do something ...
  }
```

As far as I know, the Kafka consumer application uses one thread for reading data from a single topic. This somehow violates the idea of using SSE, where for each incoming connection a dedicated long-running thread is created.

Is it a valid approach for this use-case? If so, how to accomplish this properly?

Comment: what is the purpose of replaying the kafka topic? why not use separate consumer groups? and what is your definition of `incoming connection`?

Comment: Kafka holds multi-tenant data in a single topic. For the incoming connection, I mean the HTTP Rest request made with specific headers. Based on those the Kafka consumer would filter only the relevant messages (always from the beginning, staying up-to-date as far the client is connected).

Comment: ok, so by replaying you mean re-consuming, not re-sending the data to the topic.
So you want to bring up a new consumer for each incoming connection? Not sure I fully grasped your intent...

Comment: Yes - re-consuming.

Comment: I'm ignoring here the aspects of fault tolerance - what happen if your process dies and how you restore those SSEs (as this can obviously be solved). 

A kafka consumer application doesn't necessarily have one thread to read from single topic. An application can run multiple threads (consumers)  of same consumer group reading from same topic or multiple topics. And you can also have an application with multiple consumer groups reading from same or different topics. It's totally up to you, don't think there's right or wrong. I'd tend to go with different apps for different consumer groups...